# How to query all users that share atleast one college

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to query all users that share at least one similar attribute/content (in this case, college).

## models.py

```py
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True,
    nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False) 
    colleges = db.relationship('College', backref='author',
    lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}, {}, {}".format(self.username, self.email,
        self.image_file)



class College(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), 
    nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.content)
```

in terminal to test db

```py
#after creating db
user_1 = User(username='name',
         email='example@demo.com',password='password')
db.session.add(user_1)
db.session.commit()
user = User.query.filter_by(username='name').first()
college_1 = College(content='College1', user_id=user.id)
college_2 = College(content="College2', user_id=user.id)
db.session.add(college_1)
db.session.add(college_2)
db.session.commit()
```

At this point I want to query all users that contain at least one of the colleges (between college_1 or college_2). So I want to return the id of user_1 (and others as I add on) by querying for all users that contain at least college_1 or college_2.

I tried this query:

```py
User.query.filter_by(colleges="Dartmorth").all()
```

But it returns ' "Can't compare a collection to an object or collection; " sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't compare a collection to an object or collection; use contains() to test for membership.'

Comment: Try `College.query.filter_by(content="Dartmorth").all()` it's going to return all the colleges that have that content, then you can grab the user_id from each one.

Comment: All it returns is 'Dartmouth', how would I grab the user_id? @ElSam

Comment: It should returns a list of `College` instances, which you can iterate through and extract the user_id, e.g `colleges = College.query.filter_by(content="Dartmorth").all()` `colleges[0].user_id`

Comment: @ElSam It works! Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad I helped, please mark my answer below then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of querying on the `User` model, you need to query the `College` one:

```
colleges = College.query.filter_by(content="Dartmorth").all()
```

It should returns a list of College instances, granted it's not empty, you can iterate through it and extract the user_id:

```
user_0 = colleges[0].user_id
```